# StrongSwan connected to Cisco ASA 5550 but no traffic

Tags: vpn, routing, strongswan

[image]
I have a StrongSwan Client running on a system that doubles as a webserver successfully connected to a Cisco ASA. The problem is I cannot ping anything on the other end.

I had the same issue attempting to communicate with a watchguard VPN. it was recommend to  read up on [route based VPNs](https://docs.strongswan.org/docs/5.9/features/routeBasedVpn.html) and Virtual IPs. I did that but I'm still missing or not understanding something.

The client told me "You will need to configure a 1:1 bidirectional NAT rule between the local IP of your host and the allocated address." As a programmer I have a narrow understanding of networking but I've made some attempts to read and execute based on my interpretation.

The endpoints:

```
172.31.89.153 - Webserver / VPN StrongSwan Client internal IP
10.255.16.123 - Address allocated to the above by the Host
209.79.141.251 - The host's public address
209.79.141.30 - Remote client that should be reachable via the tunnel
```

ipsec.conf

```
conn DEST
     left=172.31.89.153
     leftid=172.31.89.153
     leftsubnet=10.255.16.123/32
     right=209.79.141.251
     rightid=209.79.141.251
     rightsubnet=209.79.141.30
     auto=add
```

### Steps I've taken so far

**I created a GRE tunnel**

```
sudo ip tunnel add gre1 local 172.31.89.153 remote 209.79.141.251 mode gre
```

**and added routing for the traffic**

```
sudo ip route add 10.255.16.123 dev gre1
sudo ip route add 209.79.141.31/32 dev gre1
```

**Verified ip forwarding is enabled on my system**

**Attempted to ping a device on the host's network that is expected to be reachable: FAILED**
**Attempted to ping from the allocated IP**

```
ping -I 10.255.16.123 209.79.141.31
ping: bind: Cannot assign requested address
```

**Tried strongswan.conf > install_routes= yes and no**

**My routing table:**

```
default via 172.31.80.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.31.89.153 metric 100
10.255.16.123 dev gre1 scope link
172.31.0.2 via 172.31.80.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp src 172.31.89.153 metric 100
172.31.80.0/20 dev ens5 proto kernel scope link src 172.31.89.153 metric 100
172.31.80.1 dev ens5 proto dhcp scope link src 172.31.89.153 metric 100
209.79.141.31 dev gre1 scope link
```

**Interfaces:**

```
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: ens5: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 9001 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:47:57:87:6e:97 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.89.153/20 metric 100 brd 172.31.95.255 scope global dynamic ens5
       valid_lft 2215sec preferred_lft 2215sec
15: gre0@NONE: <NOARP> mtu 1476 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/gre 0.0.0.0 brd 0.0.0.0
16: gretap0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1462 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
17: erspan0@NONE: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1450 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
22: gre1@NONE: <POINTOPOINT,NOARP,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 8977 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/gre 172.31.89.153 peer 209.79.141.251
    inet6 fe80::ac1f:5999/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

Comment: Is 10.255.16.123 your address or is it the remote address? Is 209.79.141.31 your address or is it the remote address? What are the connection parameters you've been told that you're *supposed to* have? Not in terms of "I ran this and that" shell commands or config files, but in plain English.

Comment: Re the very first step, _`ip tunnel add gre1 local 172.31.89.153 remote 209.79.141.251 mode gre`_ - Is 209.79.141.251 reachable from your client endpoint? Is that the ASA?

Comment: @roaima , correct 209.79.141.251 is a reference to the remote ASA and it is reachable.

Comment: @u1686_grawity I added a some more info and pics to clarify the endpoints. 209.79.141.31 is  a remote address behind the ASA.